# MySQL Query to find record between start/end time within day of week

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

We're a radio station with a program grid of shows that have start and end times, on specific day(s) of the week, on specific weeks of the year. We have shows that run overnight from Saturday to Sunday (11pm Sat - 1 am Sun) and also have shows that are scheduled Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

We're attempting to create a query to MySQL of what show is On-Air at a certain time. Our current query is incapable of such a thing.

How can we construct a query or queries to the current table providing just a time, day of week, week of year. Does the table need to be altered to include more information? Thank you.

We've tried the following table construct and MySQL query.

**MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `shows` (
    `id`        tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
    `name`      varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Program Name',
    `starts`    time NOT NULL COMMENT 'Starting Time',
    `ends`      time NOT NULL COMMENT 'Ending Time',
    `duration`  smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Length in seconds',
    `days` set('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Starting Day of the Week',
    `weeks`     set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weeks of the Year',
    `active`     tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Active Program'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**PHP:**

```
$time = date("H:i:s"); // current time
$dow = date("l"); // current Day of Week
$week = date("W");// current week

$query = "SELECT id, name, starts, ends, duration, days, weeks, active
          FROM shows WHERE starts < $time AND ends > $time
          AND FIND_IN_SET('$dow', days)
          AND FIND_IN_SET('$week', weeks)
          AND active = '1'";
```

**Sample Data:** *Show starts on Saturday 11pm, ends on Sunday 1am*

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Overnight Show",
    "starts": "23:00:00",
    "ends": "01:00:00",
    "duration": "7200",
    "days": "Saturday",
    "weeks": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53",
    "active": "1"
}
```

For a given input of $time = 00:12:00, $dow = Sunday, $weeks = 52 this returns an empty result set because the show starts on Saturday.

Comment: Since you have a start time and a duration, you don't need an end time - calculate it by adding the duration to the start day & start time. That will solve the midnight crossing problem. I'd probably combine start day and start time into a single timestamp column. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: For your set variables you should be using [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) e.g. `FIND_IN_SET($dow, days)` rather than `days LIKE '%$dow%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep you current schema you could change your query this way:

```
$time = date("H:i:s"); // current time
$dow = date("l"); // current day of Week
$dow_ystd = date("l", time() - 60*60*24); // day of Week of yesterday
$week = date("W");// current week

$query = "SELECT id, name, starts, ends, duration, days, weeks, active
          FROM shows WHERE

          (
            ( (ends > starts) AND (FIND_IN_SET('$dow', days)) AND (starts <= '$time') AND (ends >= '$time') )
            OR
            ( (ends <= starts) AND (FIND_IN_SET('$dow_ystd', days)) AND (ends > '$time') )
          )
        AND FIND_IN_SET('$week', weeks)
        AND active = '1'";
```

Please, keep in mind that this **doesn't handle shows during more than 24 hours** (i.e. spanning multiple days). To support this scenario, you'll have to change the schema more deeply.

Comment: This looks like it could be the solution, I'll do some further testing! One minor modification in the first WHERE clause before the OR for the off chance someone queries a show at the exact start time. 

starts **<=** '$time' and ends **>=** '$time'

Comment: @Ass3mbler please check if we have no weeks in database table the day is `Thursday` and start time is `10:40` and end time is `05:00`. records not showing, please check this link [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a1fbb/13](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a1fbb/13)

Answer (score 0):

Your table has (at least) two problems:

- Having both start and end time but only start day, means that your show starts and ends within the same day (in the example from sat. at 23 to sat. at 1--in the past, or during a whole week).
- Using a list of strings as a value is not only inefficient (which can be forgiven if there aren't many rows), but also brings problems, for example looking for the 2nd week with `%2%` will match `2`, `12`, `22` and so on. A workaround for this would be to add a comma `,` at the beginning of the value and other at the end of the value, and search for `%,2,%` (you have to add the `,`, in the data or during the query with `concat()`, because otherwise it won't match the first nor the last values).

The actual solution would be to add two tables:

- Your current `shows`, but without `starts`, `ends`, `days` and `weeks`
- `shows_schedule` with the start time *and duration* (not end time)
- `shows_schedule_weeks` where you'll have one row per week

Give me some time and I'll add an example.